# How to join two tables for phone codes

Tags: t-sql

I have the two tables.

The first table tbl1:

```
name nvarchar(255)
number nvarchar(255)
```

The second table dbo.phone_codes:

```
country nvarchar(255)
code nvarchar(4)
```

The first query:

```
Select Name, Number
from dbo.tbl1
```

I am getting this result:

```
User1   375xxxxxxxx
User1   7xxxxxxxxxx
User2   49xxxxxxxxx
```

The second query:

```
select country, code
from dbo.phone_codes
```

I am getting result:

```
Belarus 375
Russian 7
Germany 49
Poland  48
```

What should I use the query if I want get this result:

```
User1   37552222222 Belarus 375
User1   77333333333 Russian 7
User2   49111111111 Germany 49
```

The first table:

```
name - nvarchar(255)
number - nvarchar(255)
```

The second table:

```
country - nvarchar(255)
code - nvarchar(4)
```

Comment: what are the datatypes of number and code columns?

Comment: show table structures for both tables.

Comment: Why not clean up the table and put the code in another column?  You can have a computed column to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
 t.Name, t.Number, p.country, p.code
FROM dbo.tbl1 t
INNER JOIN dbo.phone_codes p
  ON t.Number LIKE p.code + '%'
```

Comment: Bahamas code is 1242 and US Code is 1. It will show a phone number from bahamas under US and bahamas. Bermuda and antigua code also starts from 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.Name, t.Number, p.Country, p.Cpde     
FROM
    dbo.tbl1 t, dbo.phone_codes p
WHERE
    charindex(p.Code, t.Number) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your phone number and country code consists only of numbers, no spaces, brackets, dashes or plus sign. You can try something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM( 
        SELECT T.Name , 
               T.Number ,
               P.country ,
               P.code ,                    
               RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY T.Number 
                            ORDER BY ISNULL(CAST(P.code AS int), 1) DESC)RNK
          FROM
               dbo.tbl1 T LEFT JOIN dbo.phone_codes P
               ON T.Number LIKE P.Code + '%'
      )A
  WHERE A.RNK = 1;
```

If you have special characters, you need to use `replace` function to remove any non-numeric characters.

**Rank function** is used to resolve the cases like Bermuda (1441) and US(1).

Comment: Are you getting error or incorect result? Can you please create an example using [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3). So that it will easy to see your issue.